# If rank is 1 show text "User"

Tags: php, mysql, rank

I want some behavior like:

- If in the users table the rank is set to 1 the text `"User"` will be shown.
- When it is 10 the text `"Owner"` will be shown.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please show piece of code

Comment: I don't really have code relating to that.
Thats why i'm asking.

Comment: What code do you already have? `switch($rank) {case 1: echo 'User'; break; case 10: echo 'Owner'; break;}`

Comment: in this you want like the rank is equal or greater than 1 or less then 10 is show as user yes

Comment: Sounds like a simple [if .. else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) statement. You really should check out some [PHP tutorials](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/index.php) if this is news to you, or you will be stuck on questions like this the whole day :)

Answer (score 0):

according to what you tell

```
if($rank<='9')
{
    echo'user';
}
if($rank=='10')
{
   echo 'Owner'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but..
When i set my rank to 1 it works but when i set my rank to 10 it also shows up user

Comment: @JordDuineveld no. Computers do not make errors when comparing results. If the condition `$rank<='9'` is true, what it means is that `$rank` is lesser or equal to `'9'`. check your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just comparing rank value to 1 and 10, try this

```
echo ($rank == 1) ? 'User' : 'Owner';
```

Comment: Please specify a bit more about the code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the following does not work might be that you compare strings. Note that the string `'1'` is considered less than `'9'`.

```
if($rank<='9')
{
    echo 'User';
}
if($rank=='10')
{
    echo 'Owner'; 
}
```

You should compare the rank with an ordinal value. Try this:

```
if($rank<=9)
{
    echo 'User';
}
if($rank==10)
{
    echo 'Owner'; 
}
```